grpc_tools.protoc compiling grpc with edition = 2023 fails
I'm using protoc version 28.3 on macos:
> protoc --version
libprotoc 28.3

This version can generate gRPC for typescript and go and C++, with the appropriate plugins.
It can also generate plain protobuf:
> protoc --experimental_editions -I src/proto3 --python_out=./src/generated/python/revepb src/proto3/*.proto
>

However, when I try to generate grpc, it fails:
> uv run python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --experimental_editions -I src/proto3 --python_out=./src/generated/python/revepb src/proto3/*.proto
basetypes.generated.proto: is an editions file, but code generator --python_out hasn't been updated to support editions yet.  Please ask the owner of this code generator to add support or switch back to proto2/proto3.

This makes no sense because --python_out works well in isolation.
The closest I can think of would be that grpc_tools might include its own flavor of protoc, AND that tool hasn't been updated for two years or something.
These are the versions:
+ grpcio==1.67.1
+ grpcio-tools==1.67.1
+ protobuf==5.28.3
+ setuptools==75.5.0

1.67.1 is the latest released version, from October 28 2024.
What else can I check, version-wise?
I assume, perhaps wrongly, that "use grpc with editions in python" is a mainstream thing that I should expect to work, given that python is a core language inside google -- is this assumption wrong?
What else can I do to make this work?

One clue:

uv run python3 -m grpc.tools.protoc --version
libprotoc 25.1

WTH!?

I'm unable to repro your issue (on Linux), I tried:

python w/ venv
Installed uv (interesting) and tried python w/ venv

Yes, grpc_tools bundles a (current) protoc binary:
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --version
libprotoc 27.2

You're missing the --grpc_python_out directive to generate service and rpc bindings:
# Includes:
# 1. `--pyi_out` for Python type-checking (not gRPC :-()
# 2. `--grpc_python_out` for Python gRPC service|rpc stubs
python3 \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--experimental_editions \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
--grpc_python_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/foo.proto 

And, using a gRPC-enabled variant of Player:
foo.proto:
// Edition version of proto2 file
edition = "2023";

package com.example;

message Player {
  // fields have explicit presence, so no explicit setting needed
  string name = 1;
  // to match the proto2 behavior, LEGACY_REQUIRED is set at the field level
  int32 id = 2 [features.field_presence = LEGACY_REQUIRED];
  // to match the proto2 behavior, EXPANDED is set at the field level
  repeated int32 scores = 3 [features.repeated_field_encoding = EXPANDED];

  enum Handed {
    // this overrides the default edition 2023 behavior, which is OPEN
    option features.enum_type = CLOSED;
    HANDED_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
    HANDED_LEFT = 1;
    HANDED_RIGHT = 2;
    HANDED_AMBIDEXTROUS = 3;
  }

  Handed handed = 4;

  reserved gender;
}

// Some gRPC service
service Foo {
  // Some gRPC method
  rpc Fooey (Player) returns (Player) {}
}

Yields:
.
├── foo_pb2_grpc.py
├── foo_pb2.py
├── foo_pb2.pyi
└── foo.proto

From:
python3 -m venv venv && \
source venv/bin/activate && \
python3 -m pip install grpcio && \
python3 -m pip install grpcio-tools && \
python3 -m pip freeze

grpcio==1.67.1
grpcio-tools==1.67.1
protobuf==5.28.3


Thanks for the attempt.
So, why does my grpcio_tools.protoc use an old protobuf library, but yours doesn't?
How do I even debug this?
I took out the grpc part in an attempt to simplify the debug flow.

After I answered, I realized you'd said Mac OS. The library uses protoc as a shared library. I wonder whether the version you're getting on Mac OS is outdated. What do you get with python -m grpc_tools.protoc --version?

Actually it turns out our monorepo had some totally different package that pinned opentelemetry-exporter to an older version which held protobuf to an older version which caused this problem. Finding and fixing this, it now works.
Thanks for the help and verification!
(Title: Professional Snake Wrangler)
